# When I create Windows Azure Load Balanced VM's my web application does not render the Ajax Controls correctly

Tags: asp.net, ajax, azure, telerik, load-balancing

I have:
1 Cloud Service with 3 VM's(load balanced) each with the same website loaded in IIS(.net framework 4.5).

When only one VM1 is active, the page and site renders Ajax controls correctly. But as soon as I start adding VM's, the web pages Ajax controls do not render correctly.
This is an intermittent problem, it works sometimes but most times it fails.

I suspect that it is the load balancing that's causing the issue?

Comment: I think you should ask your question here : http://superuser.com/ You'll get more answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something goes wrong with the webresource requests, probably the URLs are generated from one machine, but requested from another where the URL cannot be decrypted.

Make sure the machineKeys are identical, this may help in decrypting the URLs. Check for broken requests first, of course.

Another option is using CDNs to get resources from edge servers, not from your servers:

skins: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager-cdn-support.html

scripts: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-cdn-support.html

Comment: It was the machineKeys that weren't applied in my webconfig file as soon as I added it. It worked! Thanks

Comment: glad I could help. This may also help you: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-03-01/integrate-radcontrols-for-asp.net-ajax-in-a-webfarm-or-webgarden